# Passing default values to AddNew component

Tags: rally

I'm trying to pre-populate create defect popup and I'm not clear on what key/values I can pass. The documentation says the keys should be 'Name' and 'Description' but they are not being picked up. However, after looking around I noticed that it's picking up 'defaultName'.
Any help is appreciated!

`

```
       function onAddNewPreCreate(addNew, eventArgs)
       {
           eventArgs.item["defaultName"] = "name";
           eventArgs.item["Description"] = "description";
           eventArgs.item["defaultDescription"] = "description123";
       } 
       function onLoad() {

       var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                 '__PROJECT_OID__',
                 '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

       var addNewConfig = {
         types : ["Defect"]
       };

       var addNew = new rally.sdk.ui.AddNewArtifact(addNewConfig, rallyDataSource);
      addNew.addEventListener('onPreCreate', onAddNewPreCreate);;
       addNew.display("addNewDiv");
   }

    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the list of fields supported for the AddNewArtifact (as well as  rally.sdk.util.Navigation.popupCreatePage) is not well-documented. Description is not one of the fields supported for pre-population into the editor window. The fields that are supported for pre-population are:

```
User Story:
defaultName
rank
iteration
release
parent
dpyOid {dependency}

Defect:
defaultName
defectSuiteOid {Defect Suites}
testCaseResult
testCase
requirement
iteration

Defect Suite:
defaultName
rank
iteration

Portfolio Item:
defaultName
rank
parent

Task:
workProduct

Test Case:
testfolderOid {Test Folder}
artifactOid {Artifact}

Test Set:
iteration
release
```

Comment: Thank you! I was really hoping to pre-populate Description. That's where most of the information goes. Any ideas on if and when it might be supported?

Comment: Seems like Description would be a good one to include - not sure when that might be implemented. I'd recommend posting it as an Idea out on Rally Ideas: http://ideas.rallydev.com to gain votes/traction for such functionality.